# Unable to pass result of a function to global scope in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, web-scraping

I'm using the [images-scraper](https://github.com/pevers/images-scraper) package for node.js to search for images relating to a given search string. The package returns an array of results correctly. I'm trying to pass one element of that array (the url of the image) to a variable that I can use in another package via the global scope.

Here is my code:

```
var Scraper = require ('images-scraper')
  , bing = new Scraper.Bing();

bing.list({
    keyword: 'search string here',
    num: 1,
    detail: true
})
.then(function (res) {
    console.log('url of image result', res[0]['url']);
    global.url_result = res[0]['url'];      
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('err',err);
})

console.log('array',global.url_result);
```

The package works - the console returns the URL of the image from `res[0]['url']` when told to print it to the console within the function, however the console log outside the function returns `global.url_result` as undefined. Any advice on how I can achieve access to that result outside of the function? If I shouldn't be using global scope, what's the best way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the global not being set yet. Your `bing.list(...).then(...)` returns a promise and thus is asynchronous. For this reason your global is not yet declared outside the scope. You can tell your global isn't declared yet since your console logs happen out of the order you were expecting. The order they happened in though is no mishap and is the way that promises were created so you'll need to learn more about them to avoid future mistakes like the one you just made.

I would read up on promises [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises), [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and some other places.

But I would use module exports instead of setting globals it is much better practice in my opinion. Module exports allow you to export variables and functions from one file to another. They are set with `module.exports = myVariable`. They can then be pulled into other files on your server using the `require` function. Note that you must use a relative directory if it is a module that was not npm installed. Relative paths start with a dot which stands for the current directory and then follow regular path conventions.

This is what I would do in your case:

Code in file **image_scraper.js**:

```
var Scraper = require ('images-scraper')
  , bing = new Scraper.Bing();

function scrapeBing (searchString) {
    return bing.list({
        keyword: searchString,
        num: 1,
        detail: true
    })
    .then(function (res) {
        console.log('url of image result', res[0]['url']);
        return res[0]['url']  
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log('err',err);
    })
}

module.exports = {
    bing: scrapeBing
};
```

Code in file **app.js** (it lies in the same directory as image_scraper.js. It doesn't have to you would just have to change the require path.)

```
var imageScraper = require('./image_scraper');

imageScraper.bing("Mario").then(function (url_result) {
    console.log("url_result", url_result);
});
```

Comment: This is great - thanks for taking the time to explain my issue as well as a better approach. Hadn't encountered module exports at all so I'll read up on this approach

Comment: @Gideon if you're comfortable with the command line you could try the learnyounode tutorial from nodeschool.io. https://nodeschool.io

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the global variable correctly, but you have an order of operations problem. You are setting global.url_result inside a then function, so it happens after the promise is completed, so the console.log is firing before the variable is set. If you wrap your log in a function and then call it in the then function, that can work

```
.then(function (res) {
    console.log('url of image result', res[0]['url']);
    global.url_result = res[0]['url'];      
    loggerFunc();
}
var loggerFunc() {
  console.log(global.url_result);
 }
```